# Enforce double width unicode symbols to use double width in Markdown or CSS

Tags: css, unicode, markdown, ascii-art

I want to control the visual width of double-width unicode characters like the [LARGE ORANGE SQUARE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f7e7/index.htm)  in Github-flavored Markdown; either using Markdown code or Html/CSS.

For instance, see the following Markdown code section that misrenders the strings in Brave on MacOS (Chromium 105, MacOS 12.6, as of 2022-09-27):

```bash
                        1 3 5 7 9
single width reference  ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
double width unicode    
double width reference  ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
                        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The double-width characters are breaking out of the monospaced grid and thus cannot be used safely in such a place, e.g., for box drawing or game rendering.

The characters render just fine in system terminals, such as iTerm2 or the VSCode terminal shown below.

[image: Correct rendering of double-width unicode in the VSCode terminal]

Therefore, this seems to be a Markdown/CSS/Html issue, probably related to the fonts used by the website and through the browser in general.

**Questions**

1. How do I get full control over the width of such unicode strings in Markdown code sections?
2. Are there other workarounds to make it work at least on Github?

Comment: Somehow related: VSCode has a setting `terminal.integrated.unicodeVersion` to control the width of such characters (with `"6"` resulting  misrendered text and `"11"` resulting in correctly rendered text in the terminal). So we would need to "set" the unicode version of the Markdown code somehow and the browser would need to respect that. 

Comment: Terminals render according to the grid, browsers render according to the font – or in this case, two fonts, as the squares are most likely from a different font than the rest of the text. The only solution would be to use a monospaced font that contains both the arrows and the squares, designed to match their unicode widths.

Answer (score 1):

### Observations

As of Oct 2022 there seems to be no way of controlling the rendered font width directly. There are some workarounds though.

Based on the comments, the observations (and status quo) are as follows.

- Terminals render characters always into a grid independent of the resulting character width. They may use more than one grid unit per character, if the character has a denoted length > 1.
- Browsers render characters not into a grid but according to the visual length of the characters; even in `<pre>` tags and for monospaced fonts.

In the browser, but also in the terminal, varying font sizes can produce varying grid behavior. This makes using wider unicode characters in code/game/art sections in the browser even more indeterministic.

Here are some `monospaced` examples of the misaligned block characters next to the correctly rendered "`↑` " indicators.

| font-size | rendering |
| --- | --- |
| "h1" | ## `↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑` |
| "p" | `↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑` |
| "sup" | <sup>`↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑`</sup> |
| reference image | [image] |

Smaller font-sizes seem to respect "the grid" defined by regular monospaced characters better. But this is not something you should rely on.

### Workarounds

**Use single-width alternatives.** Do not use non-regular-width characters for your code/games/art. Many emoji characters render just fine in monospaced text. This way your texts will work seamlessly in terminals and browsers.
For instance, "blocks" can be achieved using common single-width characters, such as `░ ▒ ▓ █`. They can be colored in the terminal using escape codes.

**Avoid width mixing.** Do not combine characters that have different visual widths. Build your art around characters with the same width. For instance,
the  blocks do align with the double-width space character 　: